# QVideoFrame no such file or directory found

Tags: qt

I am trying to use QVideoFrame library

"#include "

I get no such file or directory message...Any suggestions?

Comment: its actually #include <QVideoFrame>

Comment: Try adding "QT += multimedia" to your .pro file.